Collecting System.Diagnostics.Metrics data in Application Insights
In my application, I am exposing some metrics like this:
using System.Diagnostics.Metrics;

....

public class MyMetrics
{
    public const string Name = "My.App";
    private readonly Meter _meter;
    private readonly Counter<int> _counter;

    public MyMetrics(IMeterFactory meterFactory)
    {
        _meter = meterFactory.Create(Name);
        _counter = _meter.CreateCounter<int>("mycounter");
    }

    public void CountMe()
    {
        _counter.Add(1);
    }
}

This works, and I can see the counter when using dotnet counters
However, I would like to track these metrics to Application Insights. We are using the SDK package:
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.22.0" />

Adding my custom counter like this, does not track my metric to Insights. It does track the thread count:
services.ConfigureTelemetryModule<EventCounterCollectionModule>((module, options) =>
{
    // My counter
    module.Counters.Add(new EventCounterCollectionRequest("My.App", "mycounter"));

    // Built in counter
    module.Counters.Add(new EventCounterCollectionRequest("System.Runtime","threadpool-thread-count"));
});

So it seems that the Insights SDK only supports the EventCounter api.
Is there a way to include metrics exposed through the System.Diagnostics.Metrics API in the Application Insights data?

Where you are checking your logs?

@Harshitha I'm looking at the "Logs" in Insights, under the "customMetrics" table I think it's called.

Refer this MSDoc once

I am able to get the Custom Metrics with GetMetric.Image


I am able to log Custometrics in Application Insights by using GetMetric method and TelemetryClient.

My MyMetrics.cs file:
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights;
using System.Diagnostics.Metrics;

public class MyMetrics
{
    public const string Name = "My.App";
    private readonly Meter _meter;
    private readonly Counter<int> _counter;
    private readonly TelemetryClient _telemetryClient;

    public MyMetrics(IMeterFactory meterFactory, TelemetryClient telemetryClient)
    {
        _meter = meterFactory.Create(Name);
        _counter = _meter.CreateCounter<int>("mycounter");
        _telemetryClient = telemetryClient;
    }
    public void CountMe()
    {
        _counter.Add(1);
        _telemetryClient.GetMetric("mycountertest").TrackValue(1);
    }  
}

My Program.cs file:
builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(new Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.Extensions.ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions
{
    ConnectionString = builder.Configuration["APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING"]
});


For appsettings.json file refer my SOThread.

My Controller.cs file:
  private readonly MyMetrics _myMetrics;
  public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger, TelemetryClient tc, MyMetrics myMetrics)
   {
       _logger = logger;      
       _myMetrics = myMetrics;
   }
   
 [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
 public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
 {
     _myMetrics.CountMe();
     -----
 }

Logs:

Metrics:


The MyMetrics class should not have a dependency on application insights. The goal is to instrument the library using the dotnet metrics api, and have those get picked up by Insights, by configuring the host application (the program.cs file)
